# Facebook API can I create an Event with "Guests can invite friends" set to false?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is currently creating events for users and their friends are all allowed to invite their friends to the event. I'm using the official [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/) and can not seem to see a way to turn this off. The events my apps create are secret events but friends are allowed to invite friends. In the Facebook web app when creating an event there is a checkbox option called "Guests can invite friends". Maybe it's normal for Facebook not to allow full control via the graph API I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the privacy_type field. Its an enum with these possible values: 'OPEN', 'SECRET', 'FRIENDS'

Comment: Yes the privacy is set to SECRET which works but friends are allowed to invite friends